# No description or item name on PayPal Payment Received email

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

Using PayPal Express Checkout (via WooCommerce & [the WooThemes PayPal Express Checkout plugin](http://docs.woothemes.com/document/paypal-express-checkout/), on the e-mail that my client receives on payment (from their client), the description of the product is blank. Ideally I would want it to display the product name or at least item number, so the correct product can be shipped without matching up emails from PayPal & WooCommerce.

[image: Image of no description on paypal email]

I'm pretty sure WooCommerce is sending the information to PayPal, because when I go to purchase an item, when I click the PPE button, it will show item names & prices in PayPal (had to blur specific item names)

[image: PayPal page showing item names]

I just need some way to identify which products to send out, from the 'You received a payment of X from Y' email PayPal sends out - I have taken a look in the plugin but all information looks like it is being sent through, so I'm not sure this is on the plugin side, I looked on PayPal developer support area and they linked to here, so I figured it would be a lot faster response than waiting for an e-mail from PayPal, and I am currently waiting a reply from WooThemes in regards to the plugin

As a side note, this also happens when the sandbox mode is enabled.