# Paypal E-Mail to Seller after Payment-Process: Items have no Description/Name

Tags: email, paypal

I have a question about the PHP-Paypal-API. When paying I set the following parameters to each item:

```
$itemDetails = new PaymentDetailsItemType();
$itemDetails->Name = $item['name'];
$itemDetails->Amount = $itemAmount;
$itemDetails->Quantity = $item['count'];
$itemDetails->ItemCategory = isset($item['pp_cat']) ? $item['pp_cat'] : 'Digital';
$itemDetails->Tax = new BasicAmountType($data['currencyCode'], $item['tax']);

$paymentDetails->PaymentDetailsItem[] = $itemDetails;
```

In the shopping cart in Paypal, the names of the items are assigned correctly. The Payment works as expected. (This is only a Screenshot from a Test-Product in Sandbox, but same Code.

[image: Paypal Payment Process]

But in the E-Mail, the seller gets as soon as the payment was successfully, the description is empty. I unfortunately only have the German Mail, but maybe it will help you anyway.

[image: Empty Description ("Beschreibung")]

What Parameter should be set, so the Description in the E-Mail isn't empty?

I have also found a similar thread but there was no answer. [No description or item name on PayPal Payment Received email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21015937/no-description-or-item-name-on-paypal-payment-received-email)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly create an MTS ticket at our Technical Portal (https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/) and share the affected transaction ID further checking.